# Implement animated screen rotation in Android

Tags: android, animation, screen-rotation

how would one implement animated screen rotation in Android. Currently from the implementations I've seen, android switches screen displays abruptly.

In another operating system, iOS, the screen rotation is animated.

I have seen one Android app that seems to take a screenshot of the current interface and rotate that. There is a little lag.

With the screenshot approach how would one get that information in a nonrooted device, especially if the target audience goes back to Android 2.2 or 2.3

Ultimately, how would one implement animated screen rotation in an Android app?

Comment: Post your code, so that some one can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: If you are doing it at the application level, then you won't need to take a screen shot. The Layouts and Views will be your own so you'll be able to directly take a Bitmap of what they look like with `View.getDrawingCache()`

Comment: @FoamyGuy in that case I could just rotate my Views directly with the animation library

Comment: @CQM I don't see any reason why not, but I haven't specifically tried to implement it.